# How to sync RDS and open search (elastic search)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, opensearch

Open-Search in sync with RDS

I'm running a database on aws (rds) and I need to keep my elastic-search in sync with rds. I was wondering would it be possible to do this with logstash but I can't seem to find any examples. I know locally you can do it with elastic search but open search I'm not too sure if it is.